# My URL mixes up after going through Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing JS for a website and i am confused by this string not working as intended.

The line is:

```
var app = "<a onclick='openApp('"+url+"')">"+icon+"</a>"
```

For some reason, this leads to

```
<a onclick="openApp(" https:="" classroom.google.com')=""><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i></a>
```

The input for the var URL was `https://classroom.google.com`. Can someone explain this weird outcome?

Comment: what's the value of `url` and `icon` before this line of code? - by the way `var app = "<a onclick='openApp('"+url+"')">"+icon+"</a>"` is not valid syntax and should result in an syntax error - have you missed a `+` somewhere?

Comment: What does `openApp()` do?  Why not just let the link do its job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's tokenize your code the way that JS will do it:

```
var app = "<a onclick='openApp('"+url+"')">"+icon+"</a>"
```

```
var                                 // var keyword
app                                 // identifier named "app"
=                                   // = operator
"<a onclick='openApp('"             // String literal between double-quotes
+                                   // + operator
url                                 // identifier named "url"
+                                   // + operator
"')"                                // String literal between double quotes
>                                   // > operator!?
"+icon+"                            // String literal between double quotes
<                                   // < operator
/                                   // / operator (divide or start of regex literal)?
a                                   // "a" identifier
>                                   // > operator
"                                   // Ack, open double-quotes without closing!
```

As you can see, you have a syntax error, and I'm surprised the code runs at all instead of just throwing an error (Chrome throws an error). Based on your output, I think your actual code is this (or maybe you're using a JS engine that's converting your code to this):

```js
var app = "<a onclick='openApp('" + url + "')>" + icon + "</a>"
```

In which case, this *is* valid syntax. However, it produces invalid *HTML*:

```html
<a onclick='openApp('https://classroom.google.com')>
  <i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i>
</a>
```

Why is it invalid? Because you're opening an attribute value string for `onclick` with a `'`, so the next `'` closes the string. Therefore your HTML parser has a tricky situation:

```
<                       // Open tag
a                       // Element name "a"

onclick                 // Attribute name
=                       // Starting attribute value
'                       // Starting attribute string
openApp(                // Attribute string contents
'                       // Closing attribute string
                        // Done with onclick attribute

https:                  // Attribute name
/                       // Invalid, so ignored
/                       // Invalid, so ignored
                        // No = sign, so this is an empty "" attribute value
                        // Done with https: attribute

classroom.google.com')  // Attribute name
                        // No = sign, so this is an empty "" attribute value
                        // Done with classroom.google.com') attribute

>                       // Close tag
                        // ...
```

Hence, when the DOM is output, we now get this for your "a" tag:

```
<a
  onclick='openApp('
  https:=""
  classroom.google.com')=""
>
 ...
</a>
```

So, as others have pointed out, you need to make sure that your HTML attributes are quoted properly. Since you intend your `onclick` attribute to contain single-quotes, one approach would be to surround your `onclick` value with *double quotes* instead. This complicates things because your *JavaScript* string is delimited by double-quotes; you have a nested JS string inside of an HTML string inside of another JS string. This is where you can use an escape sequence like `\"` to say "I want this to be a double quote as content, not a double-quote as a string literal delimiter."

```
var app = "<a onclick=\"openApp('" + url + "')\">" + icon + "</a>";
```

Now your HTML will look like this, which is valid:

```
<a onclick="openApp('https://classroom.google.com')">
  <i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how to wrap the quotation marks.

```
<script>
var icon = '<i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i> Classroom';
var url="https://classroom.google.com/";
var app = "<a href='#' onclick='openApp(\""+url+"\")'>"+icon+"</a>";
document.write(app);
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the call to `openApp` in quotes?

Comment: It looks like there is a mix of JS and HTML quotation marks - single and double. I provided a sample solution. Value of "url" variable is unknown here. Hoping JS syntax is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to create anchor element using createElement()

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var url = 'https://classroom.google.com/h';
a.innerText = 'Click here'
a.setAttribute('data-link', url)
a.addEventListener('click', openURL);
document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(a);

function openURL(e) {
  var urltoOpen = e.target.getAttribute('data-link');
  window.open(urltoOpen);
};

<div class="container">

</div>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kawal/nyz8df1k/30/

Answer (score 0):

You need to warp your `url` with `"`. To do that put them inside `\`. This will escape inner `"`.

```js
var icon = "This is link"
var url = "https://classroom.google.com"
var app = "<a onclick='openApp(\""+url+"\")'>"+icon+"</a>";

document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = app;
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```